# InnerHtml Popup With Masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

**Want:**

I want a pop up build in .Net (well any code that interacts with .Net) with a Masterpage

**Notes:**

I have code that works without a Masterpage in IE7 upwards (Not test before that) and Chrome

**Issue:**

When I try to add the code to a Masterpage the 'Div' displays on the page and not as a popup.

The code below is the none masterpage version. I have tried putting the Div in both the master page and the child page with the same result.

**Code:**

***Aspx Page***

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/Annunciator.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:Button ID="btnPopUp" runat="server" Text="Show Image and Pop Up " />

           <br />
    <br />
    Test test<div id="AnnunciatorContainer" runat="server"></div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***.aspx.vb***

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub ShowAnnouncement(ByVal title As String, ByVal message As String, Optional ByVal image As String = "")

        'Need to have Announcements as a variable 
        'Need to show a photo as well

        title = Trim(title.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "").Replace("&nbsp;", " "))
        message = Trim(message.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "").Replace("&nbsp;", " "))
        image = Trim(image.Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "").Replace("&nbsp;", " "))

        If image <> "" Then image = "<img src=""" & image & """ class=""Image"" />"

        Dim data As String = "<div id=""Annunciator""><div class=""Box""><h1>" & title & "</h1><div class=""Content""><p>" & image & message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "</p><p>") & "</p></div><a href=""?"" title=""Please Continue, I confirm that I have read this announcement"">Click To Close</a></div></div>"

        AnnunciatorContainer.InnerHtml = data

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnPopUp_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPopUp.Click

        Dim vSubjectTitle As String = "Top Title"
        Dim vMainText As String = "Test message"
        Dim vImageURL As String = "Img/Show/Dock.jpg"

        ShowAnnouncement(vSubjectTitle, vMainText, vImageURL) ' show it

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You're trying to open a popup via code behind? While it can definitely be done, you should consider that opening a popup or modal dialog is inherently a client side thing, and it doesn't make much sense to involve the server in this.

Comment: You didn't provide your CSS. But I'm assuming you don't have anything in there that would cause the div to be overlaid. And even if you did, it likely wouldn't be a good attempt since you're reinventing the wheel. Since you tagged this as jQuery, perhaps you'd be interested in jQuery UI's [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Most client side UI frameworks have [some sort](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) of popup.

Comment: I looked at the jQuery but this does not work on IE7 properly. (Sadly many of my clients still use it). I found the above code worked on tablets and PC as well. The idea of going to the server is because the code is triggered by the user clicking on the gridview so there are variables.

Comment: jQuery 1.x does support IE6+ just fine, and jQuery UI can run on jQuery 1.x. Like I said, you should consider that interactions that run on the client side that do not absolutely require server side interaction should be implemented entirely in client side. It's faster for users, it saves server resources, and it decreases the amount of network traffic which is good for both ends. Regardless of whether you do it entirely in client side or not you need to use a tool like jQuery UI, Bootstrap, Ajax Control Toolkit, Lightbox etc to create your dialog. Rolling your own will be a bad implementation